# Remove comma in last vector element using cat in R

Tags: r, cat

I'm facing a small issue in R, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I want to use cat to print a message in R console using `sep` argument in `cat`. 
This is what I've tried:

```
words <- c("foo", "foo2", "foo3")
cat("words not included:", "\n", words, sep = ",")
#words not included:,
#,foo,foo2,foo3
```

As we can see commas are inserted after `:` and before `foo`.

Then I did:

```
cat("words not included:", "\n", words, sep = ",", "\n")
#words not included:,
#,foo,foo2,foo3,
```

And my desired output is:

```
#words not included:
    #foo,foo2,foo3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toString()` instead of the `sep` argument in `cat()`.

```
cat("words not included:", "\n", toString(words),  "\n")

words not included: 
 foo, foo2, foo3
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `paste` with `collapse` here:

```
words <- c("foo", "foo2", "foo3")
cat(paste("words not included:", "\n", paste(words, collapse=",")))

words not included: 
 foo,foo2,foo3
```